# How to handle async boolean value in template

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to implement a simple exception handler in my angular app, but having a problem at the last step, where I want to show message for the user via a primeng dialog box.
For testing pourposes I have a controller endpoint, where I simply throw an exception. This runs into my my http interceptor, then into exception handler, where I call my notification service's showError() method which's Subjects emit displayModal true and message string. In the error modal component I subscribe to theese Subjects. After console logging the hell out of the app, it seems, that visibility check does not run after I assign true to the dialog components showDialog variable, so the dialog window only gets visible after some other event happens on the page. Here's the code.

Interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        // retry the HTTP call once
        retry(1),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        //check statuses if you want
        if (error.status === 418) {
            // do whatever you want
            } else {
              return throwError(error);
            }
        })
      );    
    }
}
```

ErrorHandler:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {
        const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
        const logger = this.injector.get(LoggingService);
        const notifier = this.injector.get(NotificationService);

        let message;
        let stackTrace;

        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            message = errorService.getServerMessage(error);
            console.log(error.error.message);
            stackTrace = errorService.getServerStack(error);
            notifier.showError(message);
        } else {
            message = errorService.getClientMessage(error);
            stackTrace = errorService.getClientStack(error);
            notifier.showError(message);
        }

        logger.logError(message, stackTrace);

        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

NotificationService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

    // TODO: implement a proper NotificationService!

    //displayModal: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    displayModal: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    message: Subject<string> = new Subject();

    constructor() { }

    showSuccess(message: string): void {
        alert(message);
    }

    public showError(message: string): void {
        this.message.next(message);
        this.displayModal.next(true);
    }
}
```

ErrorModalComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-modal',
  templateUrl: './error-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-modal.component.css']
})
export class ErrorModalComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

    displayModalSubcription: Subscription;
    messageSub: Subscription;
    displayModal: boolean = false;
    message: string;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.messageSub = this.notificationService.message.subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
    });

    this.displayModalSubcription = this.notificationService.displayModal
        .subscribe(displayModal => {
          this.displayModal = displayModal;
    });
  }
}
```

Dialog template:

```
<p-dialog [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'visible'}" modal="true" header="Error occured" [(visible)]="displayModal" >
    {{message}}
</p-dialog>
```

If I left out the http call, and simply bind notificationService.showError() to a button, itt works, this is why I think it has to do something with the async behaviour of http calls, but I'm not sure, because the fact I already have an error means, that I have response of the http call... I quite new to angular, so still have some foggy fields.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not think Angular's automatic change detection runs when the value of a variable of a service changes. Try changing a controller variable when the service `displayModal` changes (using the Subject/Observable you are already planning to use). Also, you do not need two-way data binding in this case, `[visible]` should be enough.

Comment: rveerd! Thank you for your reply! What do you mean 'controller variable'? I've tried the Subject/Subscription way, but no success.. Please read my answer I gave to Sasan, maybe it makes the problem a bit clearer. (Primeng needs the two-way binding to close the dialog window. )

Answer (score 0):

Your notification service is marked `private` and your referencing it in your view. That should give you an error.

This `ErrorModalComponent` needs to be in the current view all the time (no matter what route you're in).

Try this:

NotificationService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

    // TODO: implement a proper NotificationService!

    displayModal = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    message = new BehaviorSubject<string>();

    constructor() { }

    showSuccess(message: string): void {
        alert(message);
    }

    public showError(message: string): void {
        this.message.next(message);
        this.displayModal.next(true);
    }

    public hideError(): void {
        this.displayModal.next(false);
    }
}
```

ErrorModalComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-modal',
  templateUrl: './error-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-modal.component.css']
})
export class ErrorModalComponent implements OnInit {

    showModal: boolean;
    message: string;

    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.notificationService.displayModal.subscribe(v => this.showModal = v);
        this.notificationService.message.subscribe(m => this.message = m);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<p-dialog [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'visible'}" 
    modal="true" 
    header="Error occured" 
    [(visible)]="showModal" >
    {{message}}
</p-dialog>
```

Your Modal needs something to close it. Bind that button to a local `closeModal` function in your component and from there call the `hideModal` function of the `notificationService`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! There is no problem with private service, but I tried with public too, nothing changed.. Yes, closeModal function would be the next step which would clear message, and set displayModal to false, but for now primeng is closing the modal via two-way binding. I've tried it with the `Subject` - `Subscription` way already. The problem is the same, there is no change detection after the ErrorModal component's variables change. All the change detection runs before displayModal is set to true. Next time the modal shows up, becuse displayModal is true, but when I colse it....

Comment: .... primeng set it to false, so next time it won't display the modal, because of the same reason, but for fourth time is appears again.. and so on, and so on..

Comment: I've edited the question to show the Subject/Subscritption way you suggested, and which behaves exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

It might be a workaround, but at least it works. I force change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef` after setting displayModal and message to true:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-modal',
  templateUrl: './error-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-modal.component.css']
})
export class ErrorModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  displayModalSubcription: Subscription;
  messageSub: Subscription;
  displayModal: boolean = false;
  message: string;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageSub = this.notificationService.message.subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    });

    this.displayModalSubcription = this.notificationService.displayModal.subscribe(displayModal => {
      this.displayModal = displayModal;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.displayModalSubcription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```